# Android MotionLayout autoTransition not working in beta7

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-animation, android-motionlayout

I want to automatically start an animation when my fragment gets displayed. I've set the `autoTransition` attribute to `animateToEnd`, but nothing happens.
I'm currently on constraintLayout beta7. When downgrading to beta6 or lower, nothing happens either except the animation being complete when the fragment enters the screen.
I've already attached a TransitionListener to the MotionLayout and observed the following:

- **On beta7** OnTransitionChange is called once with a progress value so low I'll call it 0, OnTransitionEnd is never called and my TextView stays invisible
- **On beta6 or lower** OnTransitionChange is called twice, the first time with a rather random progress value between 0 and 0.5, and the second time with 1.0. After that, OnTransitionEnd is called and my TextView is immediatly visible, no animation there.

This is the MotionScene xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000"
        motion:motionInterpolator="easeInOut"
        motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd">
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/splash_head_TextView">
            <Layout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topGuideLine"/>
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="alpha"
                motion:customFloatValue="0.0" />
        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint android:id="@id/splash_head_TextView">
            <Layout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/splash_head"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topGuideLine"/>
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="alpha"
                motion:customFloatValue="1.0" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

Comment: It works sometimes using beta7. 1 in 10 times. use beta 4 it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell why it does not work.
But I do see a few things wrong/could be improved.

android:text="@string/splash_head"
is not a layout command
Alpha

is a better way to do the alpha

And since nothing else is changing this should be all you need.

```
<Transition
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
    motion:duration="1000"
    motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd">
</Transition>
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint android:id="@id/splash_head_TextView">
       <PropertySet android:alpha="0.0" > 
    </Constraint>

</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint android:id="@id/splash_head_TextView">
       <PropertySet android:alpha="1.0" > 
    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>
```

Comment: I refactored my code according to your suggestions (looks a lot cleaner). But the animation still doesn't start...

Comment: @walli It works for me in beta6 when the start constraint set is either set as `app:currentState="@+id/start"` or moved to by using `transitionToState(R.id.start)`. Seems actually just now broken in beta7. Mind sharing your layout if it still does not work for you?